# Is !var the same as var != NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, null

I'm wondering if `!var` is the same as `var != NULL` if `var` is `char *`.

Here goes a really small POC that shows that it's not the same thing (or am I doing something wrong?) but I don't understand why.

```
int main(void) {
    char *c = NULL;
    if(!c){
        printf("1\n");
    }else{
        printf("2\n");
    }

    if(c != NULL){
        printf("1\n");
    }else{
        printf("2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1
2
```

I'm running this on a x64 Arch Linux, GCC 4.8.2

EDIT: Either I need some real sleep or you all are misreading the actual output of the program! Please read it a few times.

`!c` means "if `c` is not NULL", which is false, so it should print `2` in the first `if`, but it prints `1`!

EDIT: Indeed, I need to get some sleep. I don't know what was I thinking about. Thank you all!

Comment: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=null "When C requires the Boolean value of an expression, a false value is inferred when the expression compares equal to zero, and a true value otherwise." This is basically the c89/c90 wording. (c89 still had the _hidden boolean_ construct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!var` is equivalent to `var==NULL`.

Your first test therefore checks `if (var == NULL)`.  Your second test checks for the opposite of this so gives you the opposite result.

This behaviour of the `!` operator is described in *C11 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators* p5

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its
>   operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares
>   equal to 0.

Comment: No, my first check checks if ```c``` is different from NULL, which should be false, so it should printf ```2```

Comment: Good catch Simonc! That was easy to overlook!

Comment: @alexandernst: No, it checks if `c` is the *same* as `NULL`.

Comment: @alexandernst That isn't correct.  `!c` is equivalent to `c==0` which is equivalent to `c==NULL`.  See my edit for a pointer to the relevant section of the language standard.

Comment: Thist is not entirely true. Pointers are different. NULL does not _have_ to be represented by all-zeros, so (!p) and (p != NULL) are both kind of special (because p is a pointer type) `p` is evalueated as a pointer expression where a boolean outcome is needed.

Comment: @wildplasser Is it my answer or last comment which isn't entirely true?  If its my comment, doesn't C11 (or99) 6.3.2.3p3 hint at equivalence between NULL and 0?

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm not sure what your point is - the language spec is such that `!p` is equivalent to `0==p`.  If `p` is a pointer, then the `0` in the equivalence is the null pointer constant.

Comment: No, it is not. NULL  does not need to be 0. NULL is equivalent to `(void*) 0`. Some achitectures (read AIX) may choose a different representation (than all-zeroos) for a NULL pointer. `(p == NULL)` is architecture independent, and so is `(!p)`. And yes: they are euivalent.

Comment: @wildplasser: while null pointers don't need to be zero bits at the hardware level, at the 'C' language level `0` represents the null pointer (regardless of how it's represented at the hardware level).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if !var is the same as var != NULL if var is char *.

`!var` is equivalent to `var == NULL` if `var` is declared with an object pointer type (like `char *`).

Answer (score 2):

The expression `!var` is true whenever `var` is false, which in C means when `var` compares equal to `0`.

`NULL` is equivalent to `0` when used in pointer contexts.

Therefore, `!var` is equivalent to `var == NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`!var is the same as var != NULL`

`!var` is the same as `var == NULL`, not `!=`. Your test is flawed, in this case - `if(c != NULL){` would be the same as `if (c) {`, not `if(!c){`.

However, `NULL` is an abomination - it is typically handled via  a macro definition, so `NULL` may have a completely different meaning in your environment, which could allow your code (if written as you intended) to show what you're describing still.

Answer (score 1):

`char *c = NULL` initializes pointer `c` to `NULL`.

`if(!c)` evaluates to `if(!0)` which is true.

`if(c != NULL)` evaluates to `if(c != 0)` which is false.

Answer (score 1):

`(!c)` and `(c != NULL)` are two opposite conditions (if one is true, the other is false).

`(!c)` is equivalent to "`if(c == 0)`" or "`if(c == NULL)`", which is true since c initialized to NULL.
`(c != NULL)` equivalent to "if(c!=0)" is FALSE, since c is equal to NULL.